# remove closest input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

Ok, i have input object, when it is changed it adds another one..
also there is delete (`izdzēst`) link when you click on, it should remove last input field..
how to that? (the function for delete is `dzest` )

I guess the problem is in `$(this)`?

```
<input name="userfile[]" type="file" size=40 />
&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="dzest();return false" class="link" name="dzest" style="font-weight:normal; display:none;">Izdzēst</a><br /> 

<script>
function dzest(){
     $(this).closest('input').remove();
}
$("input[type=file]").change(function() {
    $('<input name="userfile[]" type="file" />').appendTo('body');
    $('<a href="#" onclick="dzest();return false" class="link" name="dzest" style="font-weight:normal; display:inline;">Izdzēst</a><br/>').appendTo('body');
    $('.link').css('display','inline');

});
</script>
```

Comment: Not an answer, but please: use english named functions. And add quotes: `$("input[type='file']")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `this` in your code refers to the `window` object and not the anchor.
- `closest` means the closest element **parent**, `input` can never be a parent, so you probably meant `prev()`

---

**Fixed Code**

```
$('<a href="#" onclick="dzest(this);return false" class="link" name="dzest" style="font-weight:normal; display:inline;">Izdzēst</a><br/>').appendTo('body');
<a href="#" onclick="dzest(this);return false"
```

And the function:

```
function dzest(obj){
     $(obj).prev('input').remove();
}
```

You can also use unobtrusive event handlers & delegate events.

```
$('body').on('click', '.link', function(){
        $(this).prev('input').remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this instead and lose the onclick attribute.

```
$('a[name=dzest]').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('input').remove();
});
```

Or add an ID to the delete to simplify the selector.

Comment: It's correct but an `input` can never be a parent, take a look on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10329002/601179).

Comment: Ah good catch, don't use closest much and you are right it travel only up the tree. Sweet I learned something :)